# Redirecting a user to appropriate page is not redirecting correctly. Any ideas?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I understand that there are several resources on how to redirect a user to a specific page based on his or her access level.

My issue is that my has some flaws preventing it from working correctly.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is what we are trying to do.

We have employees with grievances. These employees are provided with a link to access and file their grievances.

Once the employee has filed his/her grievance, then the employee's manager would then log in and will be redirected to a page that shows all employees who have filed grievances so they review their grievances and determine whether or not the employees are approved to meet a board to review their cases and this is where I am stuck.

There are two tables that I didn't design. So, I am trying to make the best of what I am handed.

One table, called Employee has employee username (employeeID) and password (ssn).

The other table called Details has employeeID (related to Employee table) and ManagerID also related to Employee table by EmployeeID

Once a user files his/her grievance and submits it, his/her manager's ID (EmployeeID) is saved to the details table as ManagerID.

The idea is that once a manager logs into the system and his/her ID (ManageID) is present in details table, s/he will be redirected to a page called Decision.aspx.

When I attempted coding it, everyone, including Managers are being redirected to the same page called LetterOfIntent.aspx.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Code is below:

```
StrSQL = "Select Dept, division, divisionManager, EmployeeName,Employee.EmpID, Email, SSN,Category FROM Employee e,Details d Where e.empID = d.managerID OR e.empID = @empid and SSN=@Password"


' Initialize Database Connection
Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(StrSQL, conn)

'We use parametized query to prevent sql injection attack
Dim p1 As New SqlParameter("@enpid", StrUser)
Dim p2 As New SqlParameter("@Password", StrPass)
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)
cmd.Parameters.Add(p2)


While dr.Read()
    If dr("empid") <> "" And dr("ssn") <> "" Then
        Session("fullname") = dr("empName")
        Session("dept") = dr("Dept")
        Session("password") = dr("SSN")
        Session("Email") = dr("Email")
        Session("division") = dr("division")
        Session("empid") = dr("empid")
        Session("managerID") = dr("managerId")
        Session("Cat") = dr("Category")
        BValid = True
    Else
    End If
End While

' This handles all response per validation
 If BValid = True Then
    If Session("Cat") = "Pending" Then
        Response.Redirect("~/pending.aspx")
    ElseIf Session("Cat") = "In Progress" Then
        Response.Redirect("~/inprogress.aspx")
    ElseIf Session("managerID") <> "" And Session("empid") = Session("managerID") Then '***This is a manager, send him/her to Decision page
        Response.Redirect("~/Decision.aspx")
    Else '***Ok, this is an employee trying to file grievance, send him to LetterofInternt page.
        Response.Redirect("~/LetterOfIntent.aspx?myname= " & Session("empid") & "")
    End If

    'If all else fails, then reject their athentication attempt and let them know.
ElseIf BValid = False Then
    lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red
    lblMsg.Text = "Login failed. "
End If
```

Comment: You need to debug your program. Inspect the values for Session("Cat") and other variables.

Comment: Where does the object "dr" come from?

Comment: @MattWhetton,

It came from here:

`        'open recordset to receive db values
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to ToString each of the values you're putting into session, like this:

```
Session("Cat") = dr("Category").ToString()
```

You'd need to put some null checking around each one but given the information it seems like its probably you're issue.

Comment: and Mason,

The problem doesn't appear to be with Session("Cat")

The problem is with Session("ManagerID"). When I put a debug around it, gives me a manager that is unrelated to the manager I am logging in with it

Comment: The issue is right on this line:

`ElseIf Session("managerID") <> "" And Session("empID") = Session("managerID") Then`

If the ID of the employee logging in is not the same ID as the manager in details table, then log that person in as employee and redirect to LetterOfIntent.aspx. That's where the problem lies.